# add and delete row dynamically

Tags: jquery

This is my js code:

```
<script>
function add(){
  $('#myTable tr:last').after('<tr><td>4<span onclick="del()">del row</span></td></tr>');
}
function del(){
  $(this).parent('tr').remove();
}
</script>
```

and html:

```
<table id="myTable" border="1">
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
</table>

<span onclick="add()">add row</span>
```

My add button work nice but my del button not work. When del row clicked nothing happened.

Comment: It is here: `'<tr><td>4<span onclick="del()">del row</span></td></tr>'` stop downvote!

Comment: Couple of things. **1.** `this` when using inline script is the window. **2.** you need to replace `parent` with `closest`. **3.** better use `delegate event` [see my updated answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11018956/601179).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Little change with your code

```
function add(){
  $('#myTable tr:last').after('<tr><td>4<span onclick="del(this)">del row</span></td></tr>');
}
    
function del(el) {
    $(el).closest('tr').remove()
}
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/203/)**

---

#### Another easier approach, not need radical change in your code

I think more easy will be that, if you add a class to the `del row span` and remove `onclick` like following:

```
function add(){
  $('#myTable tr:last').after('<tr><td>4<span class="delRow">del row</span></td></tr>');
}
```

and set delegate event handler like following:

```
$('#myTable').on('click', 'span.delRow', del);
```

and write your `del()` function like following:

```
function del() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
}
```

**[Working Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/200/)**

---

#### And one important note

Don't forget to place your whole code within

```
$(document).ready(function() {..})
```

in short

```
$(function() {..})
```

Comment: You don't have to delegate.  You can bind the click event when the span is created dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things.

**1.** `this` when using inline script is the window.
**2.** you need to replace `parent` with `closest`.
**3.** better use `delegate event`

```
function del(){
     $(this).closest('tr').remove(); // closest!!
}    

$('#myTable').on('click', 'span', del);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your del function to:

```
function del(row){
  $(row).closest('tr').remove();
}​
```

and your add function to:

```
$('#myTable tr:last').after('<tr><td>4<span onclick="del(this)">del row</span></td></tr>');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tEQJd/1/)**.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is not going to be span, so it's not going to find the parent.  I wouldn't create global functions for these at all nor would I use script attributes.  I would rewrite it as:

```
<table id="myTable" border="1">
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
</table>

<span id="add">add row</span>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#add").on('click', function () {
   $('#myTable tr:last').after(
      $("<tr>")
         .append($("<td>", {text: '4'})
            .append($("<span>", {text: 'del row'})
               .on('click', function () {
                  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
               })
            )
         )
   );
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
$(this).parent('#myTable tr').remove();
```